# KeyError when using Colab

Tags: python

I am working through a [regression example](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/01/21/regression-with-keras/) however, I am receiving a KeyError: 'dataset' when I run the code.

As I am using Colab, I have updated the parser as follows:

```
# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
args = {
    "input": "path/to/input_image.jpg",
    "output": "path/to/output_image.jpg"
}
```

When I run the following line, I get an error message:

```
inputPath = os.path.sep.join([args["dataset"], "HousesInfo.txt"])
```

I have changed the director to where I have installed the relevant files - any ideas what else I need to do to the code, please?

Cheers.

Comment: Well, I might be wrong, but maybe, just maybe it's because `args` does not have the key `"dataset"`?

Comment: dataset is not in the args.

Comment: Diolch yn fawr/thanks a lot :)